# R: How do I set a breakpoint in a different file?

Tags: r, debugging

I have two files:

Main.R

Called.R

Main.R has the line

source('Called.R')

Main.R calls a function in Called.R. I can step into the function in called.R, from Main.R no problem.

However, if I set a breakpoint in the function in Called.R and call that function from Main.R, execution does not stop at the breakpoint. However, if I move the function into Main.R, execution does stop.

Any idea if RStudio's debugger can recognize breakpoints set in 'sourced' files? I can't even find the problem referred to in the documentation.

Thank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a temporary `browser()` line inside of that function

Comment: simplest solution that just works and doesnt require you to have all your code inside functions

Answer (score 4):

Plus: This answer from RStudio support. I tested this and it works.

"Hi Andrew,

This is a limitation of the debugger. The debugger works by modifying a function that has already been loaded and adding breakpoints to it. When you source() a file containing a function, it replaces the function with a new copy that doesn't have breakpoints.

For debugging you can do the following:

1) Source 'called.R' manually

2) Set breakpoints in the function

3) Comment out the source("called.R") line in main.R

4) Source main.R

You should hit the breakpoint.

Jonathan."

Comment: or use the RStudio function `debugSource` instead of `source` (and don't forget to undo that before go live later ;-)